# Load New URL Content Without Refresh?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, header, content-type

I need to ask a simple question I am trying to get a page URL and replace the users current content with the new URL data without a refresh?

Here's what I have so far:

```
$("#load_more_link").click(function () {

  window.history.replaceState("object or string", "Title", "/another-new-url");
  return false;

});
```

So whatever the content of the new php or html page is I want to display that content instead.

How can I do this?

Comment: `without a refresh`.. you're looking about [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: YOu have to do a refresh of some type, if not a full page postback, you need to refresh something on the page via ajax. Are you updating the whole page or just a portion of it? If the whole page try googling "single page app".

Comment: just the posts content

Answer (score 0):

I think...

1. you need to connect to (whatever) server side proxy that does the
   retrieval of the remote url (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy), you let that
   return the complete dom. (via e.g. a jquery call to the serverside service).
2. once you have retrieved that via 
   the request to the backside, you then replace parts of
   the dom to "dump" the html content of that remote site e.g. with
   jquery after parsing it to see if there are bits in there that could
   be problematic or conflicting with code that you want to keep in the page.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you have to study a little more about callbacks.

The `$.Callbacks() function` is internally used to provide the base functionality behind the jQuery `$.ajax()` and `$.Deferred()` components. It can be used as a similar base to define functionality for new components.

Look at this link:
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.callbacks/

Comment: I know ajax though there be another method guess I can make use of ajax :D

Comment: Follow the instructions above please and let me know, also don't forget to up vote my answer or mark as, to close this topic, thank you.

Comment: before i upvote there's something i'm worried about if a clan had 1 billion or trillions at a worse case posts would selecting all posts slow the sites performance down?